# Python keep track of loop count outside of loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

So I'm having a loop run 2 times but I have another loop inside of that loop running x amount of times . I need to keep track of the loop inside count even when the first loop is done looping so I could change proxies accordingly.

```
proxyList=[proxy1,proxy2,proxy3,proxy4,proxy5]

#this will be done 2 times
for accts in acctPile:

   with requests.Session() as s:

       for loop,channel in enumerate(channelsss):

           #changes proxies each 7th loop but restarts whenever loop is over :(
           proxies = proxyList[loop // 7 % len(proxyList)]
```

The problem I'm facing is when the first loop is done looping the inside loop count restarts so it uses the same proxies.

How can I make it count from where it left at so it doesn't use the same proxies?

Comment: Use itertools.cycle

Answer (score 1):

Use an additional variable:

```
_loopCounter = 0
proxyList=[proxy1,proxy2,proxy3,proxy4,proxy5]

for accts in acctPile:
   with requests.Session() as s:
       for loop,channel in enumerate(channelsss):
           proxies = proxyList[_loopCounter // 7 % len(proxyList)]
           _loopCounter += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a generator that yields the proxies as you want them, then use that in the loops. That way both sets of logic are separate.

```
def generate_proxies():
    while True:
        for proxy in [proxy1,proxy2,proxy3,proxy4,proxy5]:
            for i in range(7):
                yield proxy

proxies = generate_proxies()

for accts in acctPile:
   with requests.Session() as s:
       for loop,channel in enumerate(channelsss):
           proxy = next(proxies)
           ...use proxy here...
```